# Count number of rows by group using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, count, plyr

I am using the `mtcars` dataset. I want to find the number of records for a particular combination of data. Something very similar to the `count(*)` group by clause in SQL. `ddply()` from *plyr* is working for me

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mtcars, .(cyl,gear),nrow)
```

has output

```
  cyl gear V1
1   4    3  1
2   4    4  8
3   4    5  2
4   6    3  2
5   6    4  4
6   6    5  1
7   8    3 12
8   8    5  2
```

Using this code

```
library(dplyr)
g <- group_by(mtcars, cyl, gear)
summarise(g, length(gear))
```

has output

```
  length(cyl)
1          32
```

I found various functions to pass in to `summarise()` but none seem to work for me. One function I found is `sum(G)`, which returned

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'G' not found
```

Tried using `n()`, which returned

```
Error in n() : This function should not be called directly
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get `group_by()` / `summarise()` to work for me?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get the same output as from `ddply`. What version of dplyr are you on? Try updating?

Comment: I have the latest version 0.1.3. Do you have 0.1.2?

Comment: Nope. Your example works just fine for me with 0.1.3.

Comment: What version of R do you have? Could that be causing the difference in behavior? I also tried this on a computer at home which is using Ubuntu, same thing..

Comment: I'm on 3.0.2, but I'd be surprised if that makes a difference, unless your version of R is very, very old.

Comment: I am on 3.0.2 as well. 

I have scoured through countless blogs and tutorials since last week before posting. If this does not work, is there another way I can count number of rows for a combination?

Comment: <shrug> Start from the beginning, try it in a clean R session with no other packages loaded. BTW, your `sum(G)` example doesn't work because presumably `G` doesn't exist. Maybe you meant `g`? And your example also works fine for me using `n()`.

Comment: The result you claim to be getting would only make sense if `g` was actually not grouped. So I would look for a reason why you might be somehow ungrouping your data frame.

Comment: It works for me too... You can try `mtcars %.% group_by(cyl, gear) %.%  summarise(length(gear))`, it gives the same result.

Comment: Thanks!!! That solved it. 

If I have both plyr and dplyr packages attached, summarise does not work as expected. As soon as I restarted the session (and did not attach all normal packages by default) I was able to make it work. Phew.

Comment: n() also works once I detached plyr package. So the main culprit plyr package that interferes with dplyr package.

Thanks for the help again!!!

Comment: FYI there's a warning on the package's [github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) page that addresses this.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Once I follow the recommended order it is working okay.

Answer (score 191):

There's a special function `n()` in dplyr to count rows (potentially within groups):

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
#Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
#Groups: cyl [?]
#
#    cyl  gear     n
#  (dbl) (dbl) (int)
#1     4     3     1
#2     4     4     8
#3     4     5     2
#4     6     3     2
#5     6     4     4
#6     6     5     1
#7     8     3    12
#8     8     5     2
```

But dplyr also offers a handy `count` function which does exactly the same with less typing:

```
count(mtcars, cyl, gear)          # or mtcars %>% count(cyl, gear)
#Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
#Groups: cyl [?]
#
#    cyl  gear     n
#  (dbl) (dbl) (int)
#1     4     3     1
#2     4     4     8
#3     4     5     2
#4     6     3     2
#5     6     4     4
#6     6     5     1
#7     8     3    12
#8     8     5     2
```

Answer (score 23):

I think what you are looking for is as follows.

```
cars_by_cylinders_gears <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

This is using the dplyr package. This is essentially the longhand version of the count () solution provided by docendo discimus.

Comment: Works for me. The crucial part is NOT specifying the quotes around column names to group by.

Answer (score 21):

Another approach is to use the double colons as this will help avoid potential conflicts with functions with similar names from other packages.

```
mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(length(gear))
```

Comment: Edited to add why using colons would be useful although I think the main point of this answer is the use of `length`

Answer (score 3):

Another option, not necesarily more elegant, but does not require to refer to a specific column:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  do(data.frame(nrow=nrow(.)))
```

This is equivalent to using `count()`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
all.equal(mtcars %>% 
            group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
            do(data.frame(n=nrow(.))) %>% 
            ungroup(),
          count(mtcars, cyl, gear), check.attributes=FALSE)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: not sure what you mean, it gives `nrow` of each group, as in `count`?

Comment: I'm not sure as this was 6 years ago. Likely some of the functions have changed. I've removed my old comment.

Comment: thanks @Hack-R!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the function [tally](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/tally) from `dplyr`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>% 
  tally()
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl  gear     n
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4     3     1
#> 2     4     4     8
#> 3     4     5     2
#> 4     6     3     2
#> 5     6     4     4
#> 6     6     5     1
#> 7     8     3    12
#> 8     8     5     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One could simply do this using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

# Use the function add_count() and name the new variable as "count"

mtcars %>%
  add_count(cyl, gear, name = "count")
```

This way you do not need to group the columns as the `add_count()` function does that for you when you mention variables. Also, this allows you to retain other variables in the data frame (if any).