# how to do a groupby and count number of occurrences in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have following dataframe in R

```
 truck_no     start_time         end_time           ctr_no    time     type
  ABC123      20-05-2016 06:53   20-05-2016 08:53   ERT09      1.67      D
  ABC123      20-05-2016 06:53   20-05-2016 08:53   TRT12      1.67      R
  ABC123      20-05-2016 06:53   20-05-2016 08:53   ERT34      1.67      R
  ABC123      20-05-2016 06:53   20-05-2016 08:53   ERT33      1.67      D
  ERT123      21-05-2016 06:53   21-05-2016 08:53   QRT34      2.67      R
  ERT123      21-05-2016 06:53   21-05-2016 08:53   PRT33      2.67      D
```

Now My desired data frame is

```
 truck_no     start_time         end_time           ctr_no   time    type
  ABC123      20-05-2016 06:53   20-05-2016 08:53   ERT09    1.67    2D2R
  ABC123      20-05-2016 06:53   20-05-2016 08:53   TRT12    2.67    1R1D
```

I want to count `D's and R's` and paste it in above manner
time is taken as a average.
How can I do it in dplyr ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767893/find-number-of-rows-using-dplyr-group-by

Comment: How do you get `ctr_no`? From my understanding it makes sense to be `ERT09` and `QRT34`. Also `truck_no` shouldn't be `ABC123` and `ERT123`?

Comment: What does "time is taken as a average" mean?

Comment: @docendodiscimus I think your answer is correct. OP messed up the expected output IMO

Comment: @Sotos, I undeleted my answer for now. Let's see if OP will respond to clarify at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a dplyr approach:

```
foo <- function(x) {y <- table(x); paste(rbind(y, names(y)), collapse = "")}

df %>% 
  group_by(truck_no) %>% 
  mutate(type = foo(type)) %>% 
  summarise_all(first)

## A tibble: 2 x 5
#  truck_no       start_time         end_time ctr_no  type
#    <fctr>           <fctr>           <fctr> <fctr> <chr>
#1   ABC123 20-05-2016 06:53 20-05-2016 08:53  ERT09  2D2R
#2   ERT123 21-05-2016 06:53 21-05-2016 08:53  QRT34  1D1R
```

In case you want the start and end time to be the mean per `truck_no` you could use the following extension:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(truck_no) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("_time")), 
            ~mean(as.POSIXct(as.character(.), format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))) %>% 
  mutate(type = foo(type)) %>% 
  summarise_all(first)
## A tibble: 2 x 5
#  truck_no          start_time            end_time ctr_no  type
#    <fctr>              <dttm>              <dttm> <fctr> <chr>
#1   ABC123 2016-05-20 06:53:00 2016-05-20 08:23:00  ERT09  2D2R
#2   ERT123 2016-05-21 06:53:00 2016-05-21 08:53:00  QRT34  1D1R
```

Comment: Your result differs from the desired result.

Comment: @Lyngbakr, you are right. The expected output seems a little unclear at the moment.