# Mutliple errors using dplyr: object not found and could not find function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am getting errors when I try to enter the code for a couple of answers to this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767893/find-number-of-rows-using-dplyr-group-by). The code is very simple, yet I still get errors.

When entering this code I get an error message:

```
 library(dplyr)
 mtcars %>% 
+   group_by(cyl, gear) %>% 
+   summarise(n = n())
```

Error: This function should not be called directly

Also, this doesn't work either:

> count(mtcars, cyl, gear)
>
> Error in count(mtcars, cyl, gear) : object 'gear' not found

Neither does this:

```
 mtcars %.% 
+   dplyr::group_by(cyl, gear) %.%
+   dplyr::summarise(length(gear))
```

> Error in mtcars %.% dplyr::group_by(cyl, gear) %.% dplyr::summarise(length(gear)) : 
>     could not find function "%.%"

However, this does work:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% do(data.frame(nrow=nrow(.)))
```

Can anyone shed some light on what is going wrong? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Separate commands should go on separate lines. Otherwise, separate them with a semicolon. 
Next, `%>%` is a piping command. It takes the output from the left side and pipes it into the input of the next function. It lets you chain multiple commands together. Thus, the `+` is not only unnecessary, it adds another error.

Hence, 
`library(dplyr) mtcars %>% + group_by(cyl, gear) %>% + summarise(n = n())` should become 
`library(dplyr); mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% summarise(n = n())` 
or more clearly:

```
    library(dplyr)
    mtcars %>% 
      group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
        summarise(n = n())
```

**EDIT**
  Syntax varies by package. I would read vignettes to get a better understanding of how the package works.