# Multi-line Time Series Chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe comprising two columns, 'host', and 'date'; which describes a series of cyber attacks against a number of different servers on specific dates over a seven month period.

Here's what the data looks like,

```
> china_atks %>% head(100)
                host       date
1     groucho-oregon 2013-03-03
2     groucho-oregon 2013-03-03
...
46 groucho-singapore 2013-03-03
48 groucho-singapore 2013-03-04
...
```

Where 'groucho-oregon', 'groucho-signapore', etc., is the hostname of the server targeted by an attack.

There are around 190,000 records, spanning 03/03/2013 to 08/09/2013, e.g.

```
> unique(china_atks$date)
  [1] "2013-03-03" "2013-03-04" "2013-03-05" "2013-03-06" "2013-03-07" 
"2013-03-08" "2013-03-09"
  [8] "2013-03-10" "2013-03-11" "2013-03-12" "2013-03-13" "2013-03-14" 
"2013-03-15" "2013-03-16"
 [15] "2013-03-17" "2013-03-18" "2013-03-19" "2013-03-20" "2013-03-21" 
"2013-03-22" "2013-03-23"
...
```

I'd like to create a multi-line time series chart that visualises how many attacks each individual server received each day over the range of dates, but I can't figure out how to pass the data to ggplot to achieve this. There are nine unique hostnames, and so the chart would show nine lines.

Thanks!

Comment: You dont have the number of attacks in the data, if yes where is it?

Comment: Each row appears to be a separate observation, so the number of attacks could be calculated by summarising this.

Comment: No the number of attacks will have to be counted in the actual data frame itself -- should this be my first step?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22767893/7347699

Comment: Please add more dates to the sample data above.

Comment: Add more rows for another date, 2 rows won't cut, however my answer should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do this.

**First Summarize the count frequency by date.**

```
library(plyr)
df <- plyr::count(da,c("host", "date"))
```

Then Do the plotting.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=freq, group=1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = host))
```

**Data**

```
 da <- structure(list(host = structure(1:4, .Label = c("groucho-eu", 
    "groucho-oregon", "groucho-singapore", "groucho-tokyo"), class = "factor"), 
        date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2013-03-03", class = "factor"), 
        freq = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("host", "date", "freq"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I had to change 'group=1' to 'group=host' for a smooth line between the points, otherwise it comes out as a sort of bar chart.

Comment: Good one. You can use `dplyr` which is next iteration of `plyr`.

Comment: @MKR Thanks! Could have done `dc <- da %>% group_by(host,date) %>% dplyr::summarise(freq = n())` but I think it would have been a bit longer.

Comment: Absolutely correct!! But i meant you could have used `dplyr::count`

Comment: @MKR makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

`ggplot2` library is capable of performing statistics. Hence, an option could be to let `ggplot` handle count/frequency. This should draw multiple lines (one for each group)

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, colour = host, group = host)) + geom_line(stat = "count")
```

**Note:** Make sure `host` is converted to `factor` to have discrete color for lines.