# How to count the data and mutate a new column for it in R

Tags: r

For example my table is shown as below

| Job | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| CEO | Male |
| Manager | Male |
| Manager | Female |
| Manager | Male |
| Supervisor | Female |

Then I would like to organize it to something like below

| Job | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CEO | 1 | 0 |
| Manager | 2 | 1 |
| Supervisor | 0 | 1 |

How can I make it right?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: what you want is called a cross-tabulation or contingency table.  There are a lot of ways to do this in R, with `table`, `xtabs` etc.  You should do some reading on these functions. It's also possible with dplyr etc but that seems like a long way around to get a simple thing.  This site summarises quite well http://analyticswithr.com/contingencytables.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of rows by group using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767893/count-number-of-rows-by-group-using-dplyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group_by` the `Job` column, then `count` the `Gender` in each `Job`. After that, transform the dataframe into a "wide" format by expanding the count result.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Job) %>% 
  count(Gender) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gender, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Job         Male Female
  <chr>      <int>  <int>
1 CEO            1      0
2 Manager        2      1
3 Supervisor     0      1
```

Or more simply, a single `table` function.

```
table(df$Job, df$Gender)

             Female Male
  CEO             0    1
  Manager         1    2
  Supervisor      1    0
```

Comment: Thank you~ It goes successful by using the second method. The first method keep showing **could not find function "pivot_wider"** even I included library **tidyverse** and **tidyr**

Comment: @JPaul If you are sure you've installed `tidyr`, you can try `tidyr::pivot_wider()`

Comment: @JPaul note that the second method returns a `table` object, not a dataframe. If you want  a dataframe, go on with `as.data.frame.matrix(table(...))`.

Answer (score 3):

Just `pivot_wider()` with `values_fn = length`:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gender, values_from = Gender, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   Job         Male Female
#   <chr>      <int>  <int>
# 1 CEO            1      0
# 2 Manager        2      1
# 3 Supervisor     0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `group_by` with `count` and `spread` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Job, Gender) %>%
  count() %>%
  spread(Gender, n, fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Job        Female  Male
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 CEO             0     1
#> 2 Manager         1     2
#> 3 Supervisor      1     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve your problem:

```
xtabs(~ Job + Gender, data=df)

            Gender
Job          Female Male
  CEO             0    1
  Manager         1    2
  Supervisor      1    0
```